# category is showing different in home page and different in product page

Tags: magento-catalog

**i have problem with catalog my root catergory is home as you can see in screen 1, and the sub category is clothes,  i save settings clear cache, then load the page the out put is screen 2, **

- instead of clothes as category i get electronics as main category
- problem two is when i click one of the catalog and enter category page i see the actual output i was expecting in the screen 3

** hence i added two sub categories **
 - one is clothes and the other electronics screen 4
 - now when i save and load the page i see the output with no catalog screen 5

any help is appreciated
thank you
am using magento 1.9.2.3

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is something wrong with url keys. Subcategory "computers" has URL key, that is equal to "mens". And also you ticked "Create Permanent Redirect for old URL". Check that url key for url rewrites are ok. Look at the table core_url_rewrite.